# Why does this render as a list of "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem"s?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to populate a DropDownList with values pulled from a property, and my end result right now is a list of nothing but "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem"s.  I'm sure there's some minor step I'm omitting here, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is.

The property GET generating the list:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllFoo {
    get {
        var foo = from g in Bar
                  orderby g.name
                  select new SelectListItem {
                     Value = g.fooid.ToString(),
                     Text = g.name
                  };

        return foo.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

The controller code:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id) {
    // n/a code
    ViewData["fooList"] = new SelectList(g.AllFoo, g.fooid);

    return View(g);
}
```

The view code:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.fooid, ViewData["fooList"] as SelectList) %>
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

EDIT:  This question is very similar to one that was already asked:

[ASP.NET MVC 2 - Html.DropDownListFor confusion with ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306527/asp-net-mvc-2-html-dropdownlistfor-confusion-with-viewmodel)

---

Otherwise, you might find this article helpful:

http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/rendering-and-binding-drop-down-lists-using-asp-net-mvc-2-editorfor/

It uses EditorFor, but the same can be done for DisplayFor.

Comment: this is not very helpful. this question asks for the specific reason why the <option> tags are rendered with nothing but "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem" in them instead of having proper text and value. Neither of your links addresses this particular problem.

Comment: Yeah, neither of those other questions or articles are "very similar" to this one. Not at all in fact.

Answer (score 33):

The problem here is that you shoudn't fill a `SelectList` with an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Use either `SelectList` or an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, but not both. For more details, have a look at this question: [Asp.Net MVC 2 Dropdown Displaying System.Web.MVC.SelectListItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832830/asp-net-mvc-2-dropdown-displaying-system-web-mvc-selectlistitem)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. You should render your List in the view like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.fooid, new 
    SelectList(ViewData["fooList"],"Text","Value", Model.DefaultValue))
```

This is based on c# with razor view