# SelectList in model not displaying in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, selectlist

refactoring my MVC page to have a better design, so here it goes.

MODEL:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SpeciesDropDown {get; set;}
}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    MyModel model = new MyModel()
    {
    SpeciesDropDown = StaticClass.GetSpeciesSelectList()
    }
```

Where GetSpeciesSelectList returns a list of values (and I know it works because it worked with viewdata.  Now the view, which works, but has a bug

```
 @model MyModel
    Species: @Html.DropDownList("SpeciesDropDown", 
    new SelectList(ViewData.Model.SpeciesDropDown))
```

which spits back a dropdownlist of a bunch of `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
@Html.DropDownList("SpeciesDropDown", 
new SelectList(ViewData.Model.SpeciesDropDown))
```

what happens when you use

```
@Html.DropDownList("SpeciesDropDown", ViewData.Model.SpeciesDropDown)
```

Have a look at this answer as well:

[Asp.Net MVC 2 Dropdown Displaying System.Web.MVC.SelectListItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832830/asp-net-mvc-2-dropdown-displaying-system-web-mvc-selectlistitem)