# MVC3 Razor SelectedValue in DropdownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I've the following code for a `DropDownListFor` and is working ok

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.Habilitacoes, New SelectList(ViewBag.Habilitacoes, "KeyHL", "DescricaoHL"), New With {.class = "FillHSpace"})
```

The `ViewBag.Habilitacoes` is a `List(Of T)`

But know I want to add the `SelectedValue` to the `DropDownListFor`, so I've used the following code but doesn't work.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.Habilitacoes, New SelectList(ViewBag.Habilitacoes, "KeyHL", "DescricaoHL", model.Habilitacoes), New With {.class = "FillHSpace"})
```

How can I declare the `SelectedValue`?

Comment: I'd use a property (e.g. `SelectedHabilitaco` - whatever that is ;) ) on the model. And use it as the first parameter of `DropDownListFor` - like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386998/dropdownlistfor-display-a-simple-list-of-strings/3387210#3387210 (see Update 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the same property as first and second argument of the DropDownListFor helper. The first argument is a scalar property and the second a collection:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.SelectedHabilitacoes, New SelectList(ViewBag.Habilitacoes, "KeyHL", "DescricaoHL"), New With {.class = "FillHSpace"})
```

and then in your controller:

```
model.SelectedHabilitacoes = "123"
```

Answer (score 0):

DropdownListFor has overloads to accomplish this

```
DropDownListFor([SelectedValue], [SelectList], optional HTML Attributes)
```

Normally you would go

```
DropDownListFor(model => model.ID, (SelectList)ViewsBag.MySelectList, optional HTML Attributes)
```

The selected value will be automatically bound to the dropdown list, and will automatically be posted the the model.ID value

if this doesn't help id ask you to post your model.