# DropDownListFor without foreach in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

ViewCode

```
public IList<Domain.Entity.Site> Sites { get; set; }
```

Controller (GetAll return a IList)

```
newViewModel.Sites = siteRepository.GetAll();
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor ?
```

I need to display a dropdown with some properties of the list items. Id and Url are some properties of these items in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It worked!**

ViewModel

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Sites {get; set;}
public string SiteSelected {get; set;}
```

Controller

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllSites()
{
    return context.SITE.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.NAME,
        Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.ID).Trim()
    }).ToList();
}

siteViewModel.Sites = GetAllSites();
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SiteSelected , Model.Sites)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the accepted answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306527/asp-net-mvc-2-html-dropdownlistfor-confusion-with-viewmodel)

You need to modify it to appropriately work with an `IList` but it is a small code change.