# Looking for help on creating DropDownListFor from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

Take a look at this link http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx where the code shows the following:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly List<IceCreamFlavor> _flavors;

    [Display(Name = "Favorite Flavor")]
    public int SelectedFlavorId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FlavorItems
    {
        get { return new SelectList(_flavors, "Id", "Name");}
    }
}
```

The line below the code block on the linked page mentions populating _flavors from a database somewhere. My question is, where would this somewhere be? Is it normal practice to pull the data directly into a ViewModel rather than the Controller? If so, would I just make a constructor and throw my DAL into it to populate _flavours? Since it's readonly, what other options would I have?

Comment: If it's readonly, then you can only set the value in the constructor and you would instantiate your viewmodel in controller obviously after getting the actual data from a service or directly from a context

Comment: Since you need to reassign your `SelectList` if you return the view after posting, it should be `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FlavorItems { get; set; }` and assign it in the controller

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago which can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387120/dropdownlistfor-without-foreach-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to make `_flavors` readonly especially when there's no constructor on the ViewModel class - looks like a mistake/typo to me. Unfortunatelly odetocode.com seems down, so I can only suggest the following solution:

Make a very simple ViewModel class

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<IceCreamFlavor> Flavors { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Favorite Flavor")]
    public int SelectedFlavorId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FlavorItems
    {
        get { return new SelectList(Flavors, "Id", "Name");}
    }
}
```

Instantiate the ViewModel in your controller action method

```
public ActionResult CreateFlavour() {
    var model = new ViewModel {
        Flavors = GetFlavorsFromDB(); // This is a fake method, supposed to get your data 
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

In your View call `DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFlavorId, Model.FlavorItems, 'Please select a flavor')
```

For more details check out my article on how to use `DropDownListFor` in ASP.NET MVC here: ['Using simple Drop Down Lists in ASP.NET MVC'](http://nimblegecko.com/using-simple-drop-down-lists-in-ASP-NET-MVC/)

Comment: You don't have a setter on `FlavorItems` so so you cant assign the value when you initialize `ViewModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke FlavorItems are just a getter - controller assigns the items to .Flavors, not .FlavorItems